# Unable to find CheckBox items with SeleniumWebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

I need to write some AUTOMATED TCs for an web application but I can`t find using SeleniumWebDriver a checkbox button .

I tried with Xpath, ClassName but nothing helps me

```
<label class ="select-label custom-control-label" for="77486440">
::before
::after
</label>
```

I expected to check / click on CheckBox item

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any checkbox in the code you've posted, my expectation is that it should be something like [`<input type="checkbox">`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp) there so I would recommend taking a closer look into your page source.

With regards to the aforementioned label you can locate it using i.e. XPath selector like:

```
//label[contains(@class,'select-label')]
```

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=21986281)
- [Selenium - Locating Elements - Locating by XPath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Comment: I try your response and I receive : Message: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : element not interactable

Comment: I try with class name :  OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <input id="7748642" type="checkbox" class="select-input custom-control-input test-checkbox-select"> is not clickable at point (293, 241). Other element would receive the click: <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">...</div>

Comment: Then update your XPath locator to be `//div[contains(@class,'custom-checkbox')]`